VSCode Regex: Capturing area codes differs from regexone.com's Exercise 2 behavior
I'm learning regex on regexone.com. In exercise 2: Matching Phone Numbers, The same patterns work differently between regexone.com and VSCode's find/replace feature.
The exercise shows these test cases:
415-555-1234
650-555-2345
(416)555-3456
202 555 4567
4035555678
1 416 555 9292

The goal is to capture only the area codes (the first three contiguous numbers) for each line which are :
415
650 
416
202 
403
416

On regexone.com, the pattern (\d{3}) successfully captures these area codes in all cases.
However, in VSCode's find/replace, this same pattern doesn't work as expected - particularly with the (416) case and the "1 416" case.
I've tried variations like:

(?:1 )?(\d{3})
^.{0,2}(\d{3})
\(?(\d{3})

But none perfectly match regexone.com's behaviour. What's the correct pattern for VSCode that will capture area codes in all these formats? And why does VSCode handle this differently?


Do you mean you only want to remove the first occurrence?

You might use an anchor with an alternation to match what could possibly come before the first 3 digits and then capture the 3 digits in group 1 ^(?:\(|1 )?(\d{3}) See https://regex101.com/r/wV7y3D/1 Another option could be (?<=^(?:\(|1 )?)\d{3} but I am not sure if that is supported in VSCODE  https://regex101.com/r/sE1Rw6/1

https://regex101.com/r/IvRkLS/2 is probably the simplest to understand: (^|\(|^\d )(\d{3}) just an alternation of 3 possibilities that may appear before the area code.  The reason (\d{3}) doesn't work the same in vscode as that web site is becuse vscode is showing you ALL matches, the web site is showing just the first.  Vscode is doing a global search over all the lines, the web site is doing a non-global search over one line at a time.  Hopefully they explained that somewhere, otherwise it is confusing.

@WiktorStribiżew Yes, I am trying to capture just the first three digits.

Then it is a usual ^(.*?)\d{3}.

Thanks guys. This is what worked to do what I needed
^(?:\(|1 )?(\d{3}).*
